# Warning on insert when use STR_TO_DATE with wrong format

Tags: mysql

this one was a litle weird, if i run the query without the insert statement, it always works, but if i try to put on my temporal table, shows han error, there are other way to validate if a date have a format or not?
This was my data from a table who all values was (varchar) this was because of usage of the table:

```
 #   c3,         c4,            c5,          import
'2019-12-17', '2020-01-01', '2021-01-01', '987654321'
'2019-12-17', '2020-01-01', '2021-01-01', '987654321'
'2019-12-17', '2020-01-01', '2021-01-01', '987654321'
'2019-12-17', '2020-01-01', '2021-01-01', '987654321'
'2019-12-17', '2020-01-01', '2021-01-01', '987654321'
'17/12/2019', '01/01/2020', '01/01/2021', '987654321'
'17/12/2019', '01/01/2020', '01/01/2021', '987654321'
```

***Sorry if this are not represented as a leggit query from DB. Only for the example.**
And i have my query:

```
create temporary table TbPoblacion (fec_emision datetime, fec_vig_de datetime, fec_vig_a datetime, importacion_id int(11));

insert into TbPoblacion(fec_emision, fec_vig_de, fec_vig_a, importacion_id)
SELECT 
CASE WHEN to_days(STR_TO_DATE(il.c3, "%d/%m/%Y")) is not null THEN STR_TO_DATE(il.c3, "%d/%m/%Y") ELSE il.c3 END date_emision, 
CASE WHEN to_days(STR_TO_DATE(il.c4, "%d/%m/%Y")) is not null THEN STR_TO_DATE(il.c4, "%d/%m/%Y") ELSE il.c4 END date_vig_from, 
CASE WHEN to_days(STR_TO_DATE(il.c5, "%d/%m/%Y")) is not null THEN STR_TO_DATE(il.c5, "%d/%m/%Y") ELSE il.c5 END date_vig_to
FROM ImportationLayout il
WHERE il.importacion_id=987654321;
```

If i run the same query without the statement it works:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN to_days(STR_TO_DATE(il.c3, "%d/%m/%Y")) is not null THEN STR_TO_DATE(il.c3, "%d/%m/%Y") ELSE il.c3 END date_emision, 
CASE WHEN to_days(STR_TO_DATE(il.c4, "%d/%m/%Y")) is not null THEN STR_TO_DATE(il.c4, "%d/%m/%Y") ELSE il.c4 END date_vig_from, 
CASE WHEN to_days(STR_TO_DATE(il.c5, "%d/%m/%Y")) is not null THEN STR_TO_DATE(il.c5, "%d/%m/%Y") ELSE il.c5 END date_vig_to
FROM ImportationLayout il
WHERE il.importacion_id=987654321;
```

[sample1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq7Mq.png)
[sampleerror2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAGY6.png)

This was the error:

> Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '2019-12-17' for function
> str_to_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `SELECT` query is used as the source for `INSERT`, some conditions that would just be warnings and return `NULL` are treated as fatal errors. That's why the `SELECT` query works by itself, but not when used with `INSERT`.

Instead of calling `str_to_date()` to see if it matches the `dd/mm/yyyy` pattern, use a simple pattern match with `LIKE`.

You're also missing the `importacion_id` column in the `SELECT` list.

```
insert into TbPoblacion(fec_emision, fec_vig_de, fec_vig_a, importacion_id)
SELECT 
CASE WHEN il.c3 LIKE '%/%/%' THEN STR_TO_DATE(il.c3, "%d/%m/%Y") ELSE il.c3 END date_emision, 
CASE WHEN il.c4 LIKE '%/%/%' THEN STR_TO_DATE(il.c4, "%d/%m/%Y") ELSE il.c4 END date_vig_from, 
CASE WHEN il.c5 LIKE '%/%/%' THEN STR_TO_DATE(il.c5, "%d/%m/%Y") ELSE il.c5 END date_vig_to,
il.importacion_id
FROM ImportationLayout il
WHERE il.importacion_id=987654321;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved the problem, every day something new is learned. I couldn't rate your answer, I would give you +1.